Bicep how to refer a parent in module when using loop
So I'm trying to write something that will allow me to create topics and subscriptions in a loop and while I think I've achieved that thanks to code founded here, I'm facing some problems and I'n not sure how to resolve them.
It looks like sometimes bicep fails because it try to create subscription when topics creation is not yet finished. When I re-run my pipeline, it works just fine. I guess this is the reason:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/bicep/linter-rule-use-parent-property
The error I get is:
The incoming request is not recognized as a namespace policy put request. ttps://aka.ms/sbResourceMgrExceptions. TrackingId:e1d2c50d-fe92-43d8-abfe-8eb2c1917a70_G5, SystemTracker:ihdev-nonprod-servicebus.servicebus.windows.net:dev-sb-topic-test/subscriptions/dev-sb-sub-test, Timestamp:2024-04-08T13:33:29 (Code: MessagingGatewayNotFoundStatusCode
I'm not sure how to avoid this error.
Is there a way to create particular subscription only if corresponding topic was created? I guess I cannot simply add dependsOn[i] as I would have to change from for topic in topicsAndSubscriptions to something like for (topic, i) in topicsAndSubscriptions but maybe I'm wrong?
Main.bicepparam:
using './main.bicep'

param serviceBusNamespaceName = '#{SBUS_NAMESPACE_NAME}#'
param topicsAndSubscriptions = [
  {
    name: 'dev-sb-top-failure'
    subscriptions: [
      'dev-sb-sub-failure'
    ]
  }
  {
    name: 'xrm-dev-sb-report-completion'
    subscriptions: [
      'dev-sb-sub-report-completion'
    ]
  }
  {
    name: 'dev-sb-top-completion'
    subscriptions: [
      'dev-sb-sub-completion'
    ]
  }
  {
    name: 'dev-sb-top-discharge'
    subscriptions: [
      'dev-sb-sub-discharge'
    ]
  }
]

Here is the code for main.bicep
@description('Name of the Service Bus namespace')
param serviceBusNamespaceName string

@description('Location for all resources.')
param location string = resourceGroup().location
param topicsAndSubscriptions array

resource serviceBusNamespace 'Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces@2022-01-01-preview' = {
  name: serviceBusNamespaceName
  location: location
  sku: {
    name: 'Premium'
  }
  properties: {}
}

resource serviceBusTopic 'Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/topics@2022-10-01-preview' = [
  for topic in topicsAndSubscriptions: {
    parent: serviceBusNamespace
    name: topic.name
    properties: {}
  }
]

module subs 'modules/subscription.bicep' = [
  for topic in topicsAndSubscriptions: {
    name: '${topic.name}-subs'
    params: {
      servicebusNamespaceName: serviceBusNamespaceName
      topicName: topic.name
      subscriptions: topic.subscriptions
    }
  }
]

module file:
param servicebusNamespaceName string
param topicName string
param subscriptions array = ['asubscription', 'anotherone']

resource sub 'Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/topics/subscriptions@2022-10-01-preview' = [
  for i in subscriptions: {
    name: '${servicebusNamespaceName}/${topicName}/${i}'
    properties: {}
  }
]


Implicit dependency is recommended in your circumstance
main.bicep
@description('Name of the Service Bus namespace')
param serviceBusNamespaceName string

@description('Location for all resources.')
param location string = resourceGroup().location
param topicsAndSubscriptions array

resource serviceBusNamespace 'Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces@2022-01-01-preview' = {
  name: serviceBusNamespaceName
  location: location
  sku: {
    name: 'Premium'
  }
  properties: {}
}

resource serviceBusTopic 'Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/topics@2022-10-01-preview' = [ for topic in topicsAndSubscriptions: {
    parent: serviceBusNamespace
    name: topic.name
    properties: {}
  }
]

module subs 'modules/subscription.bicep' = [ for (topic, i) in topicsAndSubscriptions: {
    name: '${topic.name}-subs'
    params: {
      servicebusNamespaceName: serviceBusNamespaceName
      topicName: serviceBusTopic[i].name
      subscriptions: topic.subscriptions
    }
  }
]


subscription.bicep
param servicebusNamespaceName string
param topicName string
param subscriptions array = ['asubscription', 'anotherone']

resource sub 'Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/topics/subscriptions@2022-10-01-preview' = [ for i in subscriptions: {
    name: '${servicebusNamespaceName}/${topicName}/${i}'
    properties: {}
  }
]


main.bicepparam
using './main.bicep'

param serviceBusNamespaceName = '#{SBUS_NAMESPACE_NAME}#'
param topicsAndSubscriptions = [
  {
    name: 'dev-sb-top-failure'
    subscriptions: [
      'dev-sb-sub-failure'
    ]
  }
  {
    name: 'xrm-dev-sb-report-completion'
    subscriptions: [
      'dev-sb-sub-report-completion'
    ]
  }
  {
    name: 'dev-sb-top-completion'
    subscriptions: [
      'dev-sb-sub-completion'
    ]
  }
  {
    name: 'dev-sb-top-discharge'
    subscriptions: [
      'dev-sb-sub-discharge'
    ]
  }
]

topicName: serviceBusTopic[i].name here will allow topic deployment before
corresponding subscription. I have test it, works well.

update to modules
main.bicep
@description('Name of the Service Bus namespace')
param serviceBusNamespaceName string

@description('Location for all resources.')
param location string = resourceGroup().location
param topicNames array
param subscriptionNames array

resource serviceBusNamespace 'Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces@2022-01-01-preview' = {
  name: serviceBusNamespaceName
  location: location
  sku: {
    name: 'Premium'
  }
  properties: {}
}

module topics 'modules/topic.bicep' = {
  name: 'topicDeployment'
  params: {
    serviceBusNamespaceName: serviceBusNamespaceName
    topicNames: topicNames
  }
  dependsOn:[
    serviceBusNamespace
  ]
}

module subscriptions 'modules/subscription.bicep' = {
  name: 'subsDeployment'
  params: {
    servicebusNamespaceName: serviceBusNamespaceName
    subscriptionNames: subscriptionNames
    topicNames: topicNames
  }
  dependsOn:[
    serviceBusNamespace
    topics
  ]
}


topic.bicep
param serviceBusNamespaceName string

param topicNames array

resource topicModule 'Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/topics@2022-10-01-preview' = [for (item, i) in topicNames: {
  name: '${serviceBusNamespaceName}/${item}'
}]


subscription.bicep
param servicebusNamespaceName string
param topicNames array
param subscriptionNames array

resource sub 'Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/topics/subscriptions@2022-10-01-preview' = [ for (item, i) in subscriptionNames: {
    name: '${servicebusNamespaceName}/${topicNames[i]}/${item}'
    properties: {}
  }
]


main.bicepparam
using './main.bicep'

param serviceBusNamespaceName = 'wbevent'

param topicNames = [
  'dev-sb-top-failure'
  'xrm-dev-sb-report-completion'
  'dev-sb-top-completion'
  'dev-sb-top-discharge'
]

param subscriptionNames = [
  'dev-sb-sub-failure'
  'dev-sb-sub-report-completion'
  'dev-sb-sub-completion'
  'dev-sb-sub-discharge'
]



Hmm is there any way to replace param subscriptions array = ['asubscription', 'anotherone'] and relly only on  topicsAndSubscriptions somehow? I just dont like that but true, it works :)

I'm also thinking about changing serviceBusTopic to module but I'm not entirely sure if this is possible in current approach...

I have split out the topic to modules, is this what you want?

In Bicep, the dependsOn property is used to explicitly declare that one resource should only be created after another has been successfully provisioned.
To solve your problem, you should adjust your Bicep templates to ensure that subscriptions are only created after their respective topics have been successfully created as the following:
resource serviceBusTopics 'Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/topics@2022-10-01-preview' = [
  for (topic, i) in topicsAndSubscriptions: {
    name: topic.name
    parent: serviceBusNamespace
    properties: {}
  }
]

module subs 'modules/subscription.bicep' = [
  for (topic, i) in topicsAndSubscriptions: {
    name: '${topic.name}-subs'
    params: {
      servicebusNamespaceName: serviceBusNamespaceName
      topicName: topic.name
      subscriptions: topic.subscriptions
    }
    dependsOn: [
      serviceBusTopics[i] // This ensures each subscription module waits for its corresponding topic to be created
    ]
  }
]

